# Площадь треугольника

Tags: c++, visual-studio, математика

Как вычислить площадь и периметр треугольника по 3 сторонам? Проверить возможно ли его создать?

Нашел и немного переделал вот такой пример

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "math.h"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

float qwer(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
    float d;
    d = sqrt(y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1);
    return d;
}

float per(float a, float b, float c) {
    return (a + b + c) / 2;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    float x[3], y[3];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введите координаты " << i + 1 << " точки: ";
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];
    }
    float a, b, c;
    a = qwer(x[0], x[1], y[0], y[1]);
    b = qwer(x[1], x[2], y[1], y[2]);
    c = qwer(x[2], x[0], y[2], y[0]);
    float pt;

    pt = (a, b, c);

    cout << "Площадь треугольники" << sqrt(pt*(pt - a)*(pt - b)*(pt - c)) << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

но после ввода значений выдает вот что

```
Введите координаты 1 точки: 1 2
Введите координаты 2 точки: 3 -1
Введите координаты 3 точки: 2 5
Площадь треугольника-nan(ind)
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что тут как минимум пропущена пара скобок: `d = sqrt(y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1);` А что должно означать `pt = (a, b, c);` (которое на самом деле означает `pt = c;`) - вообще теряюсь...

Comment: @Harry `pt = c;` изменить и добавить переменную выше? `float c;`

Comment: Посмотрите на описание [формулы Герона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Формула_Герона), и поправьте косяки у себя.

Comment: Правильно будет `pt=((a,b,c)+(c,a,b)+(b,c,a))/2`

Comment: А если без шуток - в `pt = ...` просто пропущен вызов функции per, определённой выше. Скобки - параметры вызова как раз.

Comment: @kkkkkkkk, по условию у вас нужно найти площадь по трем сторонам. В примере кода у вас нахождение площади по координатам его вершин. Какое условие правильное?

Comment: @insolor А по координатам вершин - куда лучше работать через произведение векторов...

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что по сути вылилось в требование написать, да не просто так, а именно вот так и эдак... Словом, по сути - учебное задание, не решавшееся самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3):

Если смотреть условие задачи текстом:

Заданы длины трех сторон.

1. Нужно проверить что треугольник существует. Треугольник не существует, если самая длинная сторона больше суммы двух других. Находите самую длинную сторону, сравниваете с суммой длин двух других. Также не помешало бы проверить, что все длины больше нуля. Хотя, если треугольник не существует, то подкоренное выражение в формуле Герона будет меньше или равно нулю, можно проверять его.
2. Смотрите описание [формулы Герона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), по ней находите площадь треугольника.
3. Находите периметр как сумму трех сторон.

Код в вопросе решает другую задачу: находит площадь по координатам трех точек. Сначала вычисляются длины сторон (a, b, c), потом используется формула Герона.

Ошибки в коде две:

- `sqrt(y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1)` - квадратный корень берется только от первой скобки. Добавьте общие скобки: `sqrt((y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1) + (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1))`
- `pt = (a, b, c);` - здесь предполагается вызов функции вычисления полупериметра (в коде это `per`) для последующего использования в формуле Герона. Собственно, пропущено имя функции, должно быть так: `pt = per(a, b, c);` 

  Или проще: `pr = (a + b + c) / 2;` Полупериметр у вас вычисляется один раз, вычисляется в одну строку, зачем заводить для этого отдельную функцию?

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    double x[3], y[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введите координаты " << i + 1 << " вершины: ";
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];
    }

    cout << "Площадь треугольника "
         << fabs((x[1]-x[0])*(y[2]-y[0])-(x[2]-x[0])*(y[1]-y[0]))/2
         << endl;
}
```

Если, конечно, вы ищете по трем вершинам, как в исходном коде, а не по сторонам, как в заголовке вопроса...

По сторонам:

```
int main()
{
    double l[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Введите длину " << i + 1 << " стороны: ";
        cin >> l[i];
    }

    double p = (l[0]+l[1]+l[2])/2;

    p *= (p-l[0])*(p-l[1])*(p-l[2]);

    if (p <= 0.0)
        cout << "Треугольник не существует\n";
    else
        cout << "Площадь треугольника " << sqrt(p) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вообще мне любой, но нужен в виде использования функций или классов или методов

Comment: @kkkkkkkk Как спросили - так вам и ответили. Не дали ТЗ - получите ХЗ... **ГДЕ В ВАШЕМ ВОПРОСЕ** это *нужен в виде использования функций или классов или методов*?

Comment: я не внимательно смотрел,   это лучше моей версии, поэтому свою я не выложу.  Перед последным выводом  думаю стоит добавить  << setprecision(10).

Comment: @kkkkkkkk,  а вы берите код и перенесите в функцию.  Вам выложили решение целиком, попытайтесь  кое что  сделать   самостоятельно

Comment: @Harry да я ничего не говорю такого, спасибо за код